# How can I export all emails from my Gmail inbox to a .csv file?

Tags: gmail, export

How can I export all emails from my Gmail inbox to a .csv file?

I need to load the data into Salesforce as a case against a contact.

Comment: Email to CSV? What would a single email message look like in your CSV file?
You could always [export your Gmail inbox to a Thunderbird mailbox file](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/I077_M48NDQ), and try to make a CSV out of that.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) will let you download your Gmail messages in [MBOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format.

From there, you'd need to convert it to CSV. I haven't used any of these, but a quick search found several possible paths you could take, for instance:

- [MBOX-to-XLS Converter](http://www.coolutils.com/online/MBOX-to-XLS)
- [Aid4Mail](http://www.aid4mail.com/email-conversion)
- [mbox2csv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbox2csv/) (perl script)